# How to fetch user details on navigation header

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I wanted to fetch the user details like name, email id and image when a user logs in with google on the navigation drawer header. I successfully authenticated the user via Google sign in but the while name email and picture on the drawer is not showing.

This is my code

```
mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (mFirebaseUser == null){
    String email = mFirebaseUser.getEmail();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.USER_KEY).child(mFirebaseUser.getEmail().replace(".", ","))
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
                    Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(users.getPhotoUrl())
                            .into(mDisplayImageView);
                    mNameTextView.setText(users.getUser());
                    mEmailTextView.setText(users.getEmail());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of your user name and email to see if it works? `Log.d("TAG", users.getUser());` What is the output?

Comment: Tried. Not working. I saw some tutorials too. This works fine there but doesn't work here

Comment: What does `Log.d("TAG", users.getUser());` print?

Comment: Notifying listeners about user (firebase user id)

Comment: @JoyDey  `if (mFirebaseUser == null){}` it should be `if (mFirebaseUser != null){}`

Comment: Not working @Rohit